# How to implement the Python program in java language

Tags: java

Python has the in operator which makes it simple. but how do i implement the below python concept in java since java doesnt have the in operator. 
This is a Python program

```
secret_word = "python"
correct_letters = "oy"
count = 0
while count < len(secret_word):
    print(secret_word[count] if secret_word[count] in correct_letters else '_', end=" ")
    count += 1
```

Comment: `someString.contains(someOtherString);`

Answer (score 1):

You can mimic this with the ternary operator and `String.indexOf`:

```
System.out.println(correct_letters.indexOf(secret_word.charAt(count)) > -1 ? secret_word.charAt(count) : '_')
```

That said, you should follow @Peter's advice and use a regular expression replace:

```
System.out.println(secret_word.replaceAll("[^" + Pattern.quote(correct_letters) + "]","_"));
```

Comment: `contains()` is clearer.

Comment: @bcsb1001 Only a bit, and using indexOf with characters is much more efficient because it avoids a whole bunch of string manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do it like this at all. I would use a regex.

```
String secret_word = "python";
String correct_letters = "oy";
System.out.println(secret_word.replaceAll("[^"+correct_letters+"]", "_"));
```

This would mask all the letters except the correct one. I suspect you can use regex in python as well.